# LawTeX not generating Table of Authorities

Tags: table-of-contents, legal-style

I am using LawTeX and have found it is very hit or miss when generating the Table of Authorities.

I am using the following citations:

```
\citecase{Scarborough v. United States, 431 U.S. 563 (1977)}
\citecase{United States v. Morrison, 529 U.S. 598 (2000)}
\citecase{United States v. Lopez, 514 U.S. 549 (1995)}
\citecase{United States v. Stewart, 348 F.3d 1132 (9th Cir. 2003)}
\citecase{Payne v. Tennessee, 501 U.S. 808 (1991)}
\citecase{Smith v. Allwright, 321 U.S. 665 (1944)}
\citecase{Wickard v. Filburn, 317 U.S. 111 (1942)}
\citecase{Janus v. AFSCME, 585 U.S. (2018)}

\index{Statute}{aa@\textsc{U.S. Const.} art. I, \S 8, cl. 3.|idxpassim}

\newstatute{18 U.S.C.} {}
\newarticle{Epstein}{Richard A. Epstein}{The Proper Scope of the Commerce Power}{73 VA. L. REV. (1987)}{1387}{}
```

I have purposely put my code in a situation where it generates the error using the following main:

```
\section{Argument}
\subsection{Analysis Under Commerce Clause}
\newpage
\subsubsection{\emph{Stare decisis} does not favor \emph{Raich}}
\newpage
\subsubsection{\emph{Scarborough} is not consistent with the Court's test under \emph{Lopez}}
\newpage
\subsubsection{Machine guns have an ``attenuated effect'' on interstate commerce under \emph{Morrison}}

``\emph{Stare decisis} is not an inexorable command'' \cite{Payne} and ``\ldots when governing decisions are unworkable or are badly reasoned, ``this Court has never felt constrained to follow precedent.'' \pincite{Smith}{649}. Considered by scholars under many lenses of Constitional interpretation, \cite{Wickard} is generally viewed as a misstep in the grand scheme of this Court's historied jurisprudence on the Commerce Clause, especially in light of this Court's later rulings. \See (``Could anyone say with a straight face that the consumption of homegrown wheat is `commerce among the several states?' '') \pincite{Epstein}{1451}. When analyzing whether to adopt or overrule prescedent, this Court turns to four primary factors as established in \cite{Janus}. Those being: the quality of the decision, the workability of the decision, developments since the decision, and reliance on the decision.  \par

In addressing the first prong, the \emph{Raich} majority heavily relies on \emph{Wickard} even though this line of reasoning lies in direct conflict with both \cite{Lopez} and \cite{Morrison}. It appears Justice O'Connor shared this view, who dissenting in \emph{Raich} wrote, ``[T]he Court appears to reason that the placement of local activity in a comprehensive scheme confirms that it is essential to that scheme. If the Court is right, then \emph{Lopez} stands for nothing more than a drafting guide \ldots'' \cite[s]{Raich}(O'Connor, J., dissenting)
\subsubsection{{The 9th Circuit's original analysis of \emph{Stewart} was correct}}
```

[image: text]

As you can see, nothing is added to the table. If I move the text to a different section, it seems to arbitrarily work. This is very frustrating as the error is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

You need two compilation runs.

[image: table of authorities]

You have to do two compilation runs for output from the first run (e.g., page numbering) to flow through into the ToA in printable form on the second run. (see page 2 of the manual).

The reason is that information like page numbering is known fully only at the end of the first run; such information having been "parked" in the `.aux` file during the first run; the `.aux` file is read in at the beginning of the second run and its information inserted at the right spot.

I installed lawtex and tried your code.

After I defined a dummy Raich entry, and put in dummy values for compulsory fields, I get no error compiling under pdflatex (Lawtex uses pdfshellescape), and the usual two-pass run generates the table of contents and the index that is the table of authorities, as expected.

I have write18 enabled, so Lawtex automatically runs `makeindex` on each of the ToA parts (cases, statutes, other), so I don't have to do it manually between pdflatex runs.

MWE

```
\providecommand{\documentclassflag}{}
\documentclass[12pt,\documentclassflag]{lawbrief} 

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{newcent,microtype}
\usepackage{setspace,xcolor}
\usepackage[hyperindex=false,linkbordercolor=white,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

%%Citations

%The command \makeandletter turns the ampersand into a printable character, rather than a special alignment tab
\makeandletter

%We use \newcase because the \emph will throw off parsing in \citecase

\citecase{Scarborough v. United States, 431 U.S. 563 (1977)}
\citecase{United States v. Morrison, 529 U.S. 598 (2000)}
\citecase{United States v. Lopez, 514 U.S. 549 (1995)}
\citecase{United States v. Stewart, 348 F.3d 1132 (9th Cir. 2003)}
\citecase{Payne v. Tennessee, 501 U.S. 808 (1991)}
\citecase{Smith v. Allwright, 321 U.S. 665 (1944)}
\citecase{Wickard v. Filburn, 317 U.S. 111 (1942)}
\citecase{Janus v. AFSCME, 585 U.S. (2018)}
\citecase{Raich v. XXX, 999 XXX (9999)}%

\index{Statute}{aa@\textsc{U.S. Const.} art. I, \S 8, cl. 3.|idxpassim}

\newstatute{18 U.S.C.} {}
\newarticle{Epstein}{Richard A. Epstein}{The Proper Scope of the Commerce Power}{73 VA. L. REV. (1987)}{1387}{}


%Set the information for the title page (later produced by \makefrontmatter)
\docket{No. 99-999} 
\petitioner{p p p}
\respondents{r r r}
\circuit{\em{n}th}
\brieffor{Petitioner}
\author{Anonymous \# 999\\{\em Counsel for Petitioner}}
\address{123 Main Street \\ city state code\\ (203) 555-1234}

\questionpresented{{ q q q? \doublespacing\par }}

\begin{document}
%This commands creates the title page, table of contents, and table of authorities
\makefrontmatter

%Sets the formatting for the entire document after the front matter
\parindent=2.5em 
\setlength{\parskip}{1.25ex plus 2ex minus .5ex} 
\setstretch{1.45}  

\section{Argument}
\subsection{Analysis Under Commerce Clause}
\newpage
\subsubsection{\emph{Stare decisis} does not favor \emph{Raich}}
\newpage
\subsubsection{\emph{Scarborough} is not consistent with the Court's test under \emph{Lopez}}
\newpage
\subsubsection{Machine guns have an ``attenuated effect'' on interstate commerce under \emph{Morrison}}

``\emph{Stare decisis} is not an inexorable command'' \cite{Payne} and ``\ldots when governing decisions are unworkable or are badly reasoned, ``this Court has never felt constrained to follow precedent.'' \pincite{Smith}{649}. Considered by scholars under many lenses of Constitional interpretation, \cite{Wickard} is generally viewed as a misstep in the grand scheme of this Court's historied jurisprudence on the Commerce Clause, especially in light of this Court's later rulings. \See (``Could anyone say with a straight face that the consumption of homegrown wheat is `commerce among the several states?' '') \pincite{Epstein}{1451}. When analyzing whether to adopt or overrule prescedent, this Court turns to four primary factors as established in \cite{Janus}. Those being: the quality of the decision, the workability of the decision, developments since the decision, and reliance on the decision.  \par

In addressing the first prong, the \emph{Raich} majority heavily relies on \emph{Wickard} even though this line of reasoning lies in direct conflict with both \cite{Lopez} and \cite{Morrison}. It appears Justice O'Connor shared this view, who dissenting in \emph{Raich} wrote, ``[T]he Court appears to reason that the placement of local activity in a comprehensive scheme confirms that it is essential to that scheme. If the Court is right, then \emph{Lopez} stands for nothing more than a drafting guide \ldots'' \cite[s]{Raich}(O'Connor, J., dissenting)
\subsubsection{{The 9th Circuit's original analysis of \emph{Stewart} was correct}}
\end{document}
```